# Format table column widths to fit single column of twocolumn document

Tags: tables, formatting

I am using a two column format, and I would like the following table to fit in one column, along with text wrapping on the title row. How do I do this? Thanks.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article} 
\usepackage{array,graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{multirow}  
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}  
\begin{document}
.....

\section{Device Model}
Table shows the device scaling parameters for 45 nm down to 8 nm for the two sets of 

\begin{table} 
\centering
\begin {tabular}{ccccccc}
\toprule %
 &Year & Tech Node (nm) & Frequency Scaling Factor (/45nm) & Vdd Scaling Factor     (/45nm) &
 Capacitance Scaling Factor (/45nm) & Power Scaling Factor (/45nm)\\ \otoprule %
 \multirow {6}*{\rot{\textbf{ITRS}}} 
 & 2010  & 45 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\%\cmidrule (l){2-7}
 & 2012  & 32 & 1.09 & 0.93 & 0.70 & 0.66 \\%\cmidrule (l){2-7}
 & 2015  & 22 & 2.38 & 0.84 & 0.33 & 0.54 \\%\cmidrule (l){2-7}
 & 2018  & 16 & 3.21 & 0.75 & 0.21 & 0.38 \\%\cmidrule (l){2-7}
 & 2021  & 11 & 4.17 & 0.68 & 0.13 & 0.25 \\%\cmidrule (l){2-7}
 & 2024  & 8  & 3.85 & 0.62 & 0.08 & 0.12 \\\midrule
\multirow {6}*{\rot{\textbf{Conservative}}}
& 2008  & 45 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\%\cmidrule (l){2-7}
& 2010  & 32 & 1.10 & 0.93 & 0.75 & 0.71 \\%\cmidrule (l){2-7}
& 2012  & 22 & 1.19 & 0.88 & 0.56 & 0.52 \\%\cmidrule (l){2-7}
& 2014  & 16 & 1.25 & 0.86 & 0.42 & 0.39 \\%\cmidrule (l){2-7}
& 2016  & 11 & 1.30 & 0.84 & 0.32 & 0.29 \\%\cmidrule (l){2-7}
& 2018  & 8  & 1.34 & 0.84 & 0.24 & 0.22 \\\bottomrule
\end {tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Can you reproduce using a standard class? If not, can you provide a link for the class you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you provide more explicit structure to the header row(s). As in @cfr's solution, I use a `tabularx` environment and a modified form of the `X` column type to make the table fit into the available width. The setup of the third column may need some extra explanation: its main column type is `d` (from the `dcolumn` package) to align the numbers, but the header cell is of type (modified) `X` to allow wrapping of its material across several lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow,graphicx,tabularx,ragged2e,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\arraybackslash\Centering\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\newcommand\rot[1]{\rotatebox{90}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table} 
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{} l c d{2.0} *{4}{Y} @{}}
\toprule %
 &Year & \multicolumn{1}{Y}{Tech Node (nm)}  
 &  \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{Scaling Factor (/45nm)} \\
 \cmidrule(l){4-7}
& & & Frequency & Vdd & Capacitance & Power\\ 
\toprule %
\multirow{6}*{\rot{\textbf{ITRS}}} 
 & 2010  & 45 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\
 & 2012  & 32 & 1.09 & 0.93 & 0.70 & 0.66 \\
 & 2015  & 22 & 2.38 & 0.84 & 0.33 & 0.54 \\
 & 2018  & 16 & 3.21 & 0.75 & 0.21 & 0.38 \\
 & 2021  & 11 & 4.17 & 0.68 & 0.13 & 0.25 \\
 & 2024  & 8  & 3.85 & 0.62 & 0.08 & 0.12 \\
\midrule
\multirow{6}*{\rot{\textbf{Conservative}}}
 & 2008  & 45 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\
 & 2010  & 32 & 1.10 & 0.93 & 0.75 & 0.71 \\
 & 2012  & 22 & 1.19 & 0.88 & 0.56 & 0.52 \\
 & 2014  & 16 & 1.25 & 0.86 & 0.42 & 0.39 \\
 & 2016  & 11 & 1.30 & 0.84 & 0.32 & 0.29 \\
 & 2018  & 8  & 1.34 & 0.84 & 0.24 & 0.22 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will need adjusting since I don't have the class you are using but here is an example with `article` in `twocolumn` mode:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{array,graphicx,tabularx,threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}
\begin{document}
.....

\section{Device Model}
Table shows the device scaling parameters for 45 nm down to 8 nm for the two sets of

\begin{table}
  \small
  \caption{Small table}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin {tabularx}{\linewidth}{c*{6}{>{\hskip0pt}X}}
      \toprule %
      &Year & Tech Node (nm) & Frequency\hskip0pt\tnote{1}  & Vdd\tnote{1}  &  Capacitance\hskip0pt\tnote{1}  & Power\tnote{1} \\ \toprule %
       \multirow {6}*{\rot{\textbf{ITRS}}}
       & 2010  & 45 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\%\cmidrule (l){2-7}
       & 2012  & 32 & 1.09 & 0.93 & 0.70 & 0.66 \\%\cmidrule (l){2-7}
       & 2015  & 22 & 2.38 & 0.84 & 0.33 & 0.54 \\%\cmidrule (l){2-7}
       & 2018  & 16 & 3.21 & 0.75 & 0.21 & 0.38 \\%\cmidrule (l){2-7}
       & 2021  & 11 & 4.17 & 0.68 & 0.13 & 0.25 \\%\cmidrule (l){2-7}
       & 2024  & 8  & 3.85 & 0.62 & 0.08 & 0.12 \\\midrule
      \multirow {6}*{\rot{\textbf{Conservative}}}
      & 2008  & 45 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\%\cmidrule (l){2-7}
      & 2010  & 32 & 1.10 & 0.93 & 0.75 & 0.71 \\%\cmidrule (l){2-7}
      & 2012  & 22 & 1.19 & 0.88 & 0.56 & 0.52 \\%\cmidrule (l){2-7}
      & 2014  & 16 & 1.25 & 0.86 & 0.42 & 0.39 \\%\cmidrule (l){2-7}
      & 2016  & 11 & 1.30 & 0.84 & 0.32 & 0.29 \\%\cmidrule (l){2-7}
      & 2018  & 8  & 1.34 & 0.84 & 0.24 & 0.22 \\\bottomrule
    \end {tabularx}
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \item[1]Scaling Factor (/45nm)
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: small table]

You should probably think about aligning the columns with numbers, too, but I don't know if the class already provides facilities for that.