# How to increase font size and change table column width?

Tags: tables, formatting

I want a table to fit in only column of a page. For that I'm using resizebox:

```
\begin{table}[!t]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\caption{Sample table}
\label{table_example}
\centering
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Sr & Hypothesis & Result \\
\hline\hline
1 & May indulgence difficulty ham can put especially. Bringing remember & Proved \\
\hline
2 & Manor we shall merit by chief wound no or would. Oh towards between & Proved \\
\hline
3 & Style never met and those among great. At no or september sportsmen & Level1 Proved, Level2 Not Proved \\
\hline
4 & Cottage out enabled was entered greatly prevent message. No procured unlocked an likewise. & Level1 Proved, Level2 Not Proved \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

This gives me following output:

[image]

The font size of the contents in the table becomes shrinked? How do I increase this font size?

Also I want to increase size of second column and reduce the size of third column after increasing font size. How do I do it?

Comment: Please refer to the following questions and their answers:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/211927/134144
https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/305052/134144

Answer (score 3):

your table is wider than page width. consequently your attempt to fit it in column width with `\resizebox` also reduce font size ... only reasonable solution is redesign table such, that the text in cells is broken onto more linens and for table use font size `\small` for better fitting text in cells:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{table}[htb]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\caption{Sample table}
    \label{table_example}
\centering
\small
%\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|>{\hsize=1.2\hsize}L
                               |>{\hsize=0.8\hsize}L|}
\hline
Sr & Hypothesis & Result \\
\hline\hline
1 & May indulgence difficulty ham can put especially. Bringing remember & Proved \\
\hline
2 & Manor we shall merit by chief wound no or would. Oh towards between & Proved \\
\hline
3 & Style never met and those among great. At no or september sportsmen & Level1 Proved, Level2 Not Proved \\
\hline
4 & Cottage out enabled was entered greatly prevent message. No procured unlocked an likewise. & Level1 Proved, Level2 Not Proved \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
%}
\end{table}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

in above *mwe* is for table environment used `tabularx` for which you had prescribed table width. for columns is defined new column type `L` by help of macro `\RaggedRight` from `ragged2e` package. with this the multi line text formatting in cells is better than with centering (according to my taste). columns width ratio is also changed. if you like to have in table the same font size as it is in text, just remove `\small`., but hen the table be less nice (again to my taste).

Answer (score 1):

To  print a table that fits the columnwidth and includes text of the sane size as the surrounding text, you could use the `tabu` package as in the following MWE.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\lipsum
\lipsum

\begin{table}[!t]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\caption{Sample table}
\label{table_example}
\centering
\tabulinesep=1.2mm
\begin{tabu} to \columnwidth{|c|X[c]|X[0.5c]|}
\hline
Sr & Hypothesis & Result \\
\hline\hline
1 & May indulgence difficulty ham can put especially. Bringing remember & Proved \\
\hline
2 & Manor we shall merit by chief wound no or would. Oh towards between & Proved \\
\hline
3 & Style never met and those among great. At no or september sportsmen & Level1 Proved, Level2 Not Proved \\
\hline
4 & Cottage out enabled was entered greatly prevent message. No procured unlocked an likewise. & Level1 Proved, Level2 Not Proved \\
\hline
\end{tabu}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: with use of `tabu` you should be careful. package is buggy and not maintained.

Comment: i took liberties and ad image of table produced by your *mwe*.

Comment: @ Zarko: Thanks for adding the image and for the warning about the `tabu` package. Although I have not yet encountered any problems, I will consider switching to `tabluarx` as well.